# breaking down time intervals and assigning them to corresponding hours

Tags: pandas, timestamp

Given start_time and end_time of an event, I want to assign the corresponding duration in which hour(start_time) they belong:

For example if I have a dataframe of:

```
event      start_time       end_time       
a            8:00             8:30               
b            8:49            10:22
```

In this case hour(start_time) = 8, is assigned with 30 mins like in first row.
However if the hours of start_time and end_time are not equal like in second rows, 
then I want to split the start_time and end_time as below:

```
event      start_time       end_time        hour(start_time)      duration
a            8:00             8:30                8                 30
b            8:49            9:00                 8                 11
b            9:00            10:00                9                 60
b            10:00           10:22                10                22
```

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in pandas?

Comment: `Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in pandas?` - I think not, in pandas not exist function for this. So can you add your loop solution to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy manipulation with data are times convert to datetimes, repeat rows by difference and add or subtract timedeltas for start, end and hour columns with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), last round by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and 
[`Series.dt.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) new datetimes:

```
print (df)
  event start_time end_time
0     a       8:00     8:30
1     b       8:49    10:22

df['s'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='%H:%M')
df['e'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'], format='%H:%M')
df['hour'] = df['s'].dt.hour

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['e'].dt.hour.sub(df['hour']).add(1))]
```

---

```
idx = df.index
m1 =  idx.duplicated()
m2 =  idx.duplicated(keep='last')

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
s = df.groupby(idx).cumcount()
s1 = df.groupby(idx).cumcount(ascending=False)

df['hour'] = df['hour'].add(s)
df.loc[m1, 's'] += pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='H')
df.loc[m1, 's'] = df.loc[m1, 's'].dt.floor('H')

df.loc[m2, 'e'] -= pd.to_timedelta(s1, unit='H')
df.loc[m2, 'e'] = df.loc[m2, 'e'].dt.ceil('H')

df['duration'] = df['e'].sub(df['s']).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
df['start_time'] = df.pop('s').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df['end_time'] = df.pop('e').dt.strftime('%H:%M')

print (df)
  event start_time end_time  hour  duration
0     a      08:00    08:30     8        30
1     b      08:49    09:00     8        11
2     b      09:00    10:00     9        60
3     b      10:00    10:22    10        22
```

Comment: Thanks man, the 'repeat', 'ceil', and 'floor' are all new to me. Also before you replied i was still struggling in working it out using groupby-apply. Thanks a lot!